# fetch success returns a promise

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have implemented a external API function to return text/html when a button is clicked. But is doesn't seem return the data. instead a promise is returned.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => getData() }>
  <Text style={styles.button}>Register</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

the fetch function

```
const getData= () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", 'ABC');
    formData.append("age", 35)
    fetch(API_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    }).then(response => {
      console.log('success');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.text()))
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error');
      console.error(JSON.stringify(response));
    })
}
```

I want only the html/text response

Comment: `response.text()` _is_ a promise. (a)wait it to be resolved as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to handle the `response.JSON` first:

```
const getData= () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", 'ABC')
    formData.append("age", 35)
    fetch(API_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error')
    })
}
```

Check out [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for more details.